# Why is `vim -E` always exiting with non-zero exit code when using here-doc?

Tags: shell, vim, posix, heredoc, ex

see the following session in dash:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\n" > testfile
$ cat testfile
foo
bar
$ vim -E testfile <<-EOS
> 1
> s/foo/baz/
> x
> EOS
$ echo $?
1
$ cat testfile
baz
bar
$ vim -E testfile +'1' +'s/baz/foo/' +'x'
$ echo $?
0
$
```

I use ex-mode of vi for exchaning the string `foo` with the string `baz` by using a here-document. Apparently that works. But nevertheless vim is still existing with an exit code of `1`.

I then exchange the `baz` with `foo` again by giving the commands directly on the commandline to vim. That works too and returns with exit code of `0` (as expected).

What is the reason the here-document is always returning with an exit code of 1?

That even happens if I do not edit the file:

```
$ vim -E testfile <<-EOS
> 1
> p
> q
> EOS
foo
$ echo $?
1
$
```

What's going on there?

Comment: I get a somewhat different behaviour: with `-E`, vim always exits with 1, whether I work interactively (`vim -E testfile` and do commands manually), with the instructions on the command line, or with a heredoc. If this is for scripting, maybe sed would be a safer choice, or ex since your commands are already in ex?

Comment: I use ex-mode, because there is some "jumping around" involved, which is not possible with the stream oriented approach of sed. And on most systems ex is just calling `vim -e`, so that wouldn't change much. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to https://vi.stackexchange.com/, and the OP has [already crossposted it there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/why-is-vim-e-always-exiting-with-non-zero-exit-code-when-using-here-doc).

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/why-is-vim-e-always-exiting-with-non-zero-exit-code-when-using-here-doc) now (which seems a bit more appropriate) and got a really useful answer there: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19241/21417